# Copy URL from browser using clipboard.js

Tags: javascript, clipboard.js

I am using the Accusoft document viewer. I have a requirement for a button that when clicked will copy to the clipboard the current URL plus a page number querystring parameter. I am using clipboard.js. I know exactly how to get the current URL and how to add a page number parameter to the URL. What I don't know how to do is make clipboard.js copy a variable (such as the generated URL with page number parameter) to the clipboard. Any help on this?

Comment: Did you try to place your variable's content into an hidden div and then use this div as the clipboard.js target ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Clipboard.js creator here ;)

You can use the imperative API to achieve that:

```js
var url = document.location.href;

new Clipboard('.btn', {
  text: function() {
    return url;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.5.10/clipboard.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn">Copy</button>
```

Comment: Zeno, thanks! That works perfectly! One other question is how to make the tooltip show "copied" like your demo. There is no sample code for that one.So when the copy is completed I want to show "copied" as a tooltip that then gets replaced by the default tooltip when the mouse goes away from the button.

Comment: Awesome ;D There are tons of different ways to do that. For example, you can use Bootstrap's Tooltip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381640/tooltips-highlight-animation-with-clipboard-js-click/37395225 or some CSS-based solution. You can check clipboardjs.com source code where we use PrimerCSS: https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/tree/gh-pages

Comment: Thanks Zeno! I managed to hack together some code that works for me! Great tool and again, thanks for the input!

Comment: Zeno, I have converted my code over to using the variable method above, but here is a problem I see with both Chrome and IE when using a DOM element to store the clipboard data...it appears when you get to the line of code var clipboard = New Clipboard(domElement); sometimes that code doesn't execute because the DOM element isn't there yet. I know about $(document).ready, but since this is inside of angular I don't really want to use that. Any ideas? I need a quick fix for the current release.

Comment: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded")` is the equivalent of jQuery's `$(document).ready`

Answer (score 0):

By placing you variable's content into a div and then use it as a target for clipboard.js....
I have to admit I didn't tryed it, but it should should work.

Your button (the example of the clipboard.js site) :

```
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-target="#clipboardTarget">
    <img src="assets/clippy.svg" alt="Copy to clipboard">
</button>
<div id="clipboardTarget" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Place your variable's content into the target div:

```
var myData = "http://example.com?data=something";
$("#clipboardTarget").html(myData);
```

It is now ready to be copied.

**-----

EDIT**

Ok, after the discussion below, I really tried my solution by downloading `Clipboard.js` and tested it.
*(Someday I will learn to test my solutions before posting!)*

Turns out that it works on a `div` only if visible.
Sadly.

**So my solution is wrong.**
I leave it here anyway... As a *"don't do it, it's a false-good idea"*.

**Thanks to Michael Mahony** for his feedback.
;)

Comment: Two comments I have to add. (1) You can't get the data from a field that is set to display:none. It throws an error; (2) I originally worked around this by using a textbox and setting it to position: absolute; left: -999em so it is not visible on the screen, but can still be reached via code. It worked, but with Zeno's suggestion I am now using a variable.

Comment: @Michael Mahony: Thank you for your feedback, I appreciate. Can you tell me what is the error it trows and on which browser (for my knowledge), because I just made a test with Chrome, and it works fine. No error and I have the html inside a hidden div console logged.

Comment: @Michael Mahony: Or is it a Clipboard.js limitation ?

Comment: It says "unable to read property "text" of hidden field" or something to that effect. Perhaps a hidden div is different from a hidden form element?

Comment: I'm using property html... Like this : var hiddenDiv = $("#testID").html(); console.log(hiddenDiv);