# clipboard.js: Illegal Constructor errors occuring on JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, clipboard.js

I'm trying to run a Copy URL event using clipboard.js. I have it installed on my server and the reference to clipboard.js is there in my code. So I have this in my footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var url = document.location.href;

    new Clipboard('.btn', {
        text: function() {
    return url;
  }
});
</script>
```

And this simply for my button:

```
<button class="btn">Copy</button>
```

Simple. And there's an example on SO that does work:
[Copy URL from browser using clipboard.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442706/copy-url-from-browser-using-clipboard-js)

But mine is throwing an Illegal Constructor error on my script and I'm really puzzled as to why. Am I forgetting something that's causing this error to appear?

Here's the Stack example: [Copy URL from browser using clipboard.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442706/copy-url-from-browser-using-clipboard-js)

Here's what I got: https://dadventuresla.com/copy-link-test/

Comment: Have you tried assigning the `new Clipboard` to a variable, e.g. `var myBtn = new Clipboard(...)`?

Comment: The snippet you linked to uses version 1.5 of the script; you are using version 2+. Either follow instructions in the docs for the current version, or include v1.5 on your website instead of the newer one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per https://clipboardjs.com/ it should be `ClipboardJS`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var url = document.location.href;

    new ClipboardJS('.btn', {
        text: function() {
    return url;
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks to you both. It's working now. Funny that the other example online only used 'Clipboard'. Must have been an earlier version of the script.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo - looking at the [Clipboard docs](https://clipboardjs.com/), it shows you need to use `ClipboardJS` not `Clipboard`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = document.location.href;
    new ClipboardJS(".btn", {
        text: function() {
            return url;
        }
    });
</script>
```