# Javascript tooltip on click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a small popup tooltip to the following code to show that text was successfully copied to the clipboard when the element is clicked. I would like the tooltip to popup saying "Copied" on a click or touch in the case of mobiles for a second, then disappear untill another item is copied.

The code is as follows:

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll("td");

tds.forEach(td => {
  td.onclick = function() {
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }

  td.addEventListener("copy", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.clipboardData) {
      event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", td.textContent);
      console.log(event.clipboardData.getData("text"))
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td><td>Data 3</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: can you use libraries ?

Comment: asking cus there is question like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381640/tooltips-highlight-animation-with-clipboard-js-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an solution without using jQuery (I assume you dont use it since its not present in the code you showed us):

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll("td");

tds.forEach(td => {
  td.onclick = function() {
    document.execCommand("copy");
    // ------- code added from here -------
    this.className = 'copied';
    var td = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
       td.className = '';
    }, 1000)
    // -------      up to here      -------
  }

  td.addEventListener("copy", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.clipboardData) {
      event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", td.textContent);
      console.log(event.clipboardData.getData("text"))
    }
  });
})
```

```css
td.copied:after {
content: "copied";
background-color: red;
padding: 5px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td><td>Data 3</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

When clicking on a `td` then for one second the `copied` class is added which has an `:after` pseudo-element that acts as your desired popup