# Integrating ClipboardJS with a Tooltip sotution in a project using Bootstrap5

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip, bootstrap-5

I'm building a page that let you copy text from pre-filled input fields, I'm using Clipboradjs for this, and I'm using bootstrap for styling.

To add a tooltip to confirm the user they've got the text on their clipboard I followed this reply from ClipboardJS founder:

[Tooltips + Highlight Animation With Clipboard.js Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381640/tooltips-highlight-animation-with-clipboard-js-click)

And that worked.

Then I decided to use Bootstrap 5 while this solution uses Bootstrap 3 which supports Jquery. I did not work with the new Bootstrap and Jquery versions, I can't figure out why.

And if I could obtain a way better than a tooltip to say that the text has been copied, it could be even better! (a green disappearing message besides the copy button for example).

Comment: You are wrong about not being able to use Jquery: `Bootstrap 5 is designed to be used without jQuery, but it’s still possible to use our components with jQuery. If Bootstrap detects jQuery in the window object it’ll add all of our components in jQuery’s plugin system; this means you’ll be able to do $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip() to enable tooltips. The same goes for our other components.` - [Bootstrap-5 Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/)

Comment: Thank you, yep I have read this later. I'm limited in terms of js and jquery, unfortunately.
I'm trying to fix the issue by using Tooltipster.