# How to use Clipboard.js 2.0 with Bootstrap 5.2 Tooltip?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip, clipboard.js

I'm trying to build a page with various buttons that copy text to the clipboard and then feedback to the user the value has been copied. Value is not from user input and the value for each button is static.

This is the closest example I've found to what I want ([Tooltips + Highlight Animation With Clipboard.js Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381640/tooltips-highlight-animation-with-clipboard-js-click)) but I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap and I've found if I change the version of Bootstrap CSS or JS, or Clipboard then the example stops working.

My Javascript is knowledge is very ropey so if anyone can point out why it doesn't work with latest versions that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a javascript/bootstrap expert but I will try to share my little experience.I think the issue may lie in jQuery dependency for Bootstrap 3 and 4 ,since the script on the reference page related with tooltip is written in jQuery and Bootstrap 5 and above are now using Vanilla Javascript ,the script won't run until you add jQuery dependency to the main project ,you can see a snippet of my project where both jQuery ,ClipboardJS and Bootstrap 5.2 work fine + I have added some CSS and animations too,I have not found any conflicts in this way ,hope this can be helpful .Please check here too [Bootstrap 5.2 with jQuery](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/javascript/#optionally-using-jquery)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous"><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amaranth:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Bootstrap 5.2 and tooltips jQuery</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">

  <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.google.com">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: 'Amaranth', sans-serif;
      background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/531602/pexels-photo-531602.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      overflow: auto;
      opacity: 99%;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      position: relative;

    }




    button {
      margin: 20px;
    }

  

   
    .btn-5 {
      width: 47px;
      height: 40px;
      line-height: 42px;
      padding: 0;
      border: none;
      background: rgb(255, 27, 0);
      background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 27, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(251, 75, 2, 1) 100%);
    }

    .btn-5:hover {
      color: #f0094a;
      background: transparent;
      box-shadow: none;
    }

    .btn-5:before,
    .btn-5:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 2px;
      width: 0;
      background: #f0094a;
      box-shadow:
        -1px -1px 5px 0px #fff,
        7px 7px 20px 0px #0003,
        4px 4px 5px 0px #0002;
      transition: 400ms ease all;
    }

    .btn-5:after {
      right: inherit;
      top: inherit;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }

    .btn-5:hover:before,
    .btn-5:hover:after {
      width: 100%;
      transition: 800ms ease all;
    }    
    
    .btn-11 {
      width: 47px;
      height: 40px;
      line-height: 42px;
      padding: 0;
      border: none;
      background: rgb(232, 120, 9);
      background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(233, 106, 15) 0%, rgb(193, 130, 35) 100%);
    }

    .btn-11:hover {
      color: #ff8000;
      background: transparent;
      box-shadow: none;
    }

    .btn-11:before,
    .btn-11:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 2px;
      width: 0;
      background: #ff8000;
      box-shadow:
        -1px -1px 5px 0px #fff,
        7px 7px 20px 0px #0003,
        4px 4px 5px 0px #0002;
      transition: 400ms ease all;
    }

    .btn-11:after {
      right: inherit;
      top: inherit;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }

    .btn-11:hover:before,
    .btn-11:hover:after {
      width: 100%;
      transition: 800ms ease all;
    }

    .btn-14 {
      background: rgb(255, 151, 0);
      border: none;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .btn-14:after {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      width: 100%;
      height: 0;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -2;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #eaf818;
      background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #e0f00c 0%, #07f5e5 25%, #0f7fc9 74%, #e10cf0 81%);
      box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5),
        7px 7px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1),
        4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    .btn-14:hover {
      color: #000;
    }

    .btn-14:hover:after {
      top: auto;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .btn-14:active {
      top: 2px;
    }

    /* 15 */
    .btn-15 {
      background: #b621fe;
      border: none;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .btn-15:after {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      width: 0;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      z-index: -1;
      background-color: #663dff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5),
        7px 7px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1),
        4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    .btn-15:hover {
      color: #fff;
    }

    .btn-15:hover:after {
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .btn-15:active {
      top: 2px;
    }  

    .alfredo {
      background-color: #eaf818;
      background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #e0f00c 0%, #07f5e5 25%, #0f7fc9 74%, #e10cf0 81%);
    }

    .alfredo2 {
      background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
      background-size: 400% 400%;
      animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    @keyframes gradient {
      0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
      }

      50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
      }

      100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
      }
    }

    .css-selector {
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, #33f8a8, #33a3f8, #da1ebd, #21bae3, #7023a7);
      background-size: 1000% 1000%;

      -webkit-animation: Alfredo 2s ease infinite;
      animation: Alfredo 2s ease infinite;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes Alfredo {
      0% {
        background-position: 0% 51%
      }

      50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%
      }

      100% {
        background-position: 0% 51%
      }
    }

    @keyframes Alfredo {
      0% {
        background-position: 0% 51%
      }

      50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%
      }

      100% {
        background-position: 0% 51%
      }
    }
    

    .urgent {
      color: #ff8000;
    }

    .urgent2 {
      background-color: #ff8000
    }

    .purple {
      color: #7F00FF;
    }

    .pink {
      color: #BF40BF;
    }
    .card {
      border: none;
      height: auto;
    }

    .copy-button {
      height: 25px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative
    }

    .tip {
      background-color: #ff8000;
      padding: auto;
      line-height: 25px;
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 4px;
      z-index: 100;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 14px;
      animation-name: tip;
      animation-duration: .6s;
      animation-fill-mode: both
    }

    .tip:before {
      content: "";
      background-color: #ff8000;
      height: 10px;
      width: 10px;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      top: -4px;
      left: 17px
    }

    #copied_tip {
      animation-name: come_and_leave;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-fill-mode: both;
      bottom: -35px;
      left: 2px
    }  
    .copy {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: start;
    }
    .copied {
      visibility: hidden;
      margin-top: var(--button-content-spacing-px);
    }  

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container-fluid">  
     <div class="container-fluid" id="section1">
      <p style="padding-top: 4em;">
      <div class="p-4 p-md-5 mb-4 beta rounded-3 z bg-gradient pt-5">
        <div class="col px-0">     
        <nav class="navbar text-bg-dark">           
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3 text-bg-dark "> <span
                    class="text-line ms-3 text-bg-dark">This button will copy red fruits name on the clipboard</span> <button
                    onclick="copy('Apple,apple,apple and strawberries!','#copy_button_1')"
                    id="copy_button_1" class="btn btn-sm  btn-15 copy-button">Copy</button> </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3 text-bg-dark"> <span
                    class="text-line ms-3 text-bg-dark">This button copies some yellow fruits on the clipboard</span>
                  <button
                    onclick="copy('Banana banana and pineapple.','#copy_button_2')"
                    id="copy_button_2" class="btn btn-sm btn-5 copy-button"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-copy" width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      stroke-width="2" stroke="#ff8000" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                      <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                      <rect x="8" y="8" width="12" height="12" rx="2" />
                      <path d="M16 8v-2a2 2 0 0 0 -2 -2h-8a2 2 0 0 0 -2 2v8a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h2" />
                    </svg>Copy</button>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3 text-bg-dark"> <span
                    class="text-line ms-3">This button will copy a lorem  name on the clipboard</span> <button
                    onclick="copy('Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit','#copy_button_3')"
                    id="copy_button_3" class="btn btn-sm css-selector copy-button"><svg
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                      class="bi bi-file-earmark-arrow-down" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                      <path
                        d="M8.5 6.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v3.793L6.354 9.146a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708l2 2a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0l2-2a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8.5 10.293V6.5z" />
                      <path
                        d="M14 14V4.5L9.5 0H4a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h8a2 2 0 0 0 2-2zM9.5 3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 11 4.5h2V14a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H4a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h5.5v2z" />
                    </svg>Copy</button> </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3 text-bg-dark"> <span
                    class="text-line ms-3 ">This button will copy a lorem name on the clipboard </span> <button
                    onclick="copy('I am a cloudy button ','#copy_button_4')" id="copy_button_4"
                    class="btn btn-sm btn-11 alfredo2 copy-button"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16"
                      height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cloud-download" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                      <path
                        d="M4.406 1.342A5.53 5.53 0 0 1 8 0c2.69 0 4.923 2 5.166 4.579C14.758 4.804 16 6.137 16 7.773 16 9.569 14.502 11 12.687 11H10a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h2.688C13.979 10 15 8.988 15 7.773c0-1.216-1.02-2.228-2.313-2.228h-.5v-.5C12.188 2.825 10.328 1 8 1a4.53 4.53 0 0 0-2.941 1.1c-.757.652-1.153 1.438-1.153 2.055v.448l-.445.049C2.064 4.805 1 5.952 1 7.318 1 8.785 2.23 10 3.781 10H6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3.781C1.708 11 0 9.366 0 7.318c0-1.763 1.266-3.223 2.942-3.593.143-.863.698-1.723 1.464-2.383z" />
                      <path
                        d="M7.646 15.854a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0l3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8.5 14.293V5.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v8.793l-2.146-2.147a.5.5 0 0 0-.708.708l3 3z" />
                    </svg> Copy</button> </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3 text-bg-dark"> <span
                    class="text-line ms-3">This button will copy a lorem name on the clipboard</span>
                  <button
                    onclick="copy('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod','#copy_button_5')"
                    id="copy_button_5" class="btn btn-sm btn-14 copy-button"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-clipboard-check" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                      <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                        d="M10.854 7.146a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-1.5-1.5a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708L7.5 9.793l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z" />
                      <path
                        d="M4 1.5H3a2 2 0 0 0-2 2V14a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V3.5a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-1v1h1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1V14a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h1v-1z" />
                      <path
                        d="M9.5 1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h3zm-3-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 5 1.5v1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 6.5 4h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 11 2.5v-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 9.5 0h-3z" />
                    </svg>Copy</button>
                </div>

              </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </nav>
      <br>

  </main>
  
  <script>
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
      .forEach(tooltip => {
        new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltip)
      })
  </script>
  <script>
    function copy(text, target) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        $('#copied_tip').remove();
      }, 800);
      $(target).append("<div class='tip' id='copied_tip'>Copied!</div>");
      var input = document.createElement('input');
      input.setAttribute('value', text);
      document.body.appendChild(input);
      input.select();
      var result = document.execCommand('copy');
      document.body.removeChild(input)
      return result;

    }
  </script>
 
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@2.0.10/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
  integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
  crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @westicle Have you tried already this solution?